# Changing scope inside javascript objects

Tags: javascript, object, scope

I'm still confused when it comes to scope when working with object's methods. In the code below I have two neighbors. Each has it's own method.

```
var counter = 0;
var neighbor1 = {
  name: 'John',
  myFunction: function () {
    console.log(this.name)
    this.doStuff();
  }
};
var neighbor2 = {
  name: 'Bob',
  doOtherStuff: function () {
    console.log(this.name);
    if(counter>5) {
      return false;
    } else {
      counter++;
      this.myFunction();
    }
  }
};

neighbor1.doStuff = neighbor2.doOtherStuff;

neighbor1.myFunction();
```

I understand when I call the neighbor1.myFunction method that it will call the neighbor2.doOtherStuff method because I've used the assignment operator above. What I don't understand is why 'this' will always be the neighbor1 object (John) and never the neighbor2 object (Bob). Can someone please explain in simple terms why neighbor1 is always 'this'? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`this` is always referring/pointing to execution context(from where you executing the function, not from where you writing the function). You're invoking `this.doStuff()` at `neighbor1` and hence the this is always pointing to `neighbor1`.

If you wish to understand more about `this`, I would recommend study this awesome [material](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch1.md)